# Can I make dataframes by for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make each 10 dataframes using a for loop.

But it just keeps being overwritten.

How can I make each dataframe using for loop?

```
for i in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : list_name,
                       'year' : list_year,
                       'point' : list_point})
```

Comment: Maybe stop reassigning to df?  list.append(pd.DataFrame({... will work better.

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked `pandas` question on StackOverflow. Basic research could have saved you time in writing this post.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define 10 separate dataframes that each have their own variable names, in any kind of loop.

What you *can* do though is instantiate something like a list of dataframes, which you can freely add to with a loop.

```py
dfs = []
for _ in range(10):
    dfs.append(pd.Dataframe....)
```

Comment: In this case, dfs is a list, how do I get dataframes? 
I need to create a dataframe and save it as excel file.

Comment: `dfs` is a list.. of dataframes? so the first dataframe is `dfs[0]`, the second `dfs[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Actually, you can generate separate objects in a loop using `globals` which is not advised. **One** list or dict of many objects is preferred as you show instead of many objects in global environment.

Comment: i personally avoid anything to do with `globals` lol, caused me too many aneurysms when i first started learning the language

Comment: Not sure why globals were even brought up. Just  create the list outside the loop.  After the loop you have a list of data frames. No globals so long as this is happening inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_dfs = {}

for i in range(10):
    dict_dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame({'name' : [list_name],
                       'year' : [list_year],
                       'point' : [list_point]})
print(dict_dfs.get(1))
```

You cannot create multipe dataframes with the same name or a dynamic variable name, you can however .append() them (like mentioned by others) or create a dictionary of dataframes like this: